# How to remove an option from the Dock context menu for an application?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

The right-click context menu in the gnome-shell dock lists the following options for an application:

1. All Windows
2. New window
3. Remove from Favorites
4. Show Details
5. Quit

I would like to remove the "New Window" option for this application in my dock.  How can I do this?